# Is it possible to call several update query at once for Firestore via Cloud Functions?

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to update several documents in Firestore through a loop. It also creates many instances of update query so it is a messy solution when I try to listen to its changes on the client-side on the mobile app on Android and iOS and web client.

```
for (var item in ListOfData) {
    documentReference.update({
        SupportedCity: item
    })
    .then(function() {
        console.log("Document successfully updated!");
    })
    .catch(function(error) {
        // The document probably doesn't exist.
        console.error("Error updating document: ", error);
    });
}
```

Thanks In Advance

Comment: I'm noticing that you're not doing anything with the promise returned by update().  If you are running this in Cloud Functions, you will definitely need to deal with these promises correctly, no matter what method you use to update data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use batch.firestore(). So instead of calling update, you add it to a batch.

```
var batch = firestore.batch();
for (var item in ListOfData) {
 var reference = firestore.collection("[Collection_Path]").doc("Document_Path");
 batch.update/*set*/(reference , {
  SupportedCity: item
 });
}
batch.commit().then(function () {
 console.log("Document Updated");
});
```